# Custom CMS or Open Source?

Tags: php, image, open-source, content-management-system, e-commerce

I am building a site for my friend using PHP and MySQL (Or SQLite, I'm still debating.)  The site is aimed to sell photography online with various options.  The backend shows statistics, recent orders, etc. and allows for the client to upload images, crop them in-browser (using javascript and GD), add a watermark to the image, adjust prices, framing options, coupon codes, etc.  Upon uploading an image, the site must also resize the image, allow for a color change or preset filter, etc.  When a person buys an image on the front end, the site will be contacted using paypals IPN, an email will be sent to the buyer and administrator, and things will resume.

The front end will have the home page showing the 10 most recent uploads, 3 pages where the client can enter contextual information, and a gallery link that will show all of the images (with sorting options, such as sort by color, size, price, tag, category, etc.)

When buying an image, the user will be faced with options such as size, frame or no frame, color, signature, etc.

Given all this information, would it be easier to use a open source CMS (and which one) or design my own.  (I can design a quick system for this site in about a month or so if thats what it comes down to)

What would be the best way to get a project like this taken care of?

Thanks

Comment: Wow, no idea why this got closed. Seemed like a relevant software related question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a subjective question, and may be closed or moved to another venue.

As a small shop, there is every reason to use a service rather than having anyone build software, ever.  Custom software is expensive to create and maintain and you're usually better off with an online product that does about 80% of what you need.

There seem to be 100s of options searching "websites for photographers" in google.  Is there a real reason your friend needs a customized CMS?

If you decide that no online service is sufficient:

Do not design your own CMS unless no other option is possible and you have a large, ongoing budget.

While the project scope may be small today, over time your friend will want to add new features (facebook integration, flickr integration, login via retinal scan, etc).  By using open source they will be able to add these using off-the-shelf plugin code.

When you use an open source CMS, you make it possible for them to get other people to do work on it in the future.  Hiring a Drupal or Wordpress coder to do a couple days of custom work or support is no problem.  For another programmer to learn a custom CMS takes much longer and is more expensive.

You get to focus on the part of the project that is most valuable to your friend.  Not on creating the login system, building a flash uploader, or managing the payment flow.  Those things have been handled before by others.  Take advantage of that.

You gain valuable knowledge of a CMS that is widely used.  You learn how to read other's code and bend it to your will.  This will be helpful later when you have to build custom solutions.

I built and maintained a custom CMS for six years.  That company still has hundreds of clients using it.  If they could move them all to Drupal/Wordrpess, they'd be much happier.

One thing to be careful of: Make sure your friend can keep the CMS up to date.  There are constant security releases for these platforms because they are constantly under attack by script kiddies.  Attackers will find the flaws in your work too, but they won't have direct access to the code so they'll be slower about it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of open source cms's out there. (Drupal, Joomla, Moodle, etc)

Why waste a month re-inventing the wheel?  We use Drupal for a lot of our sites.  With the theming capabilities, user management and data storage functionality "out-of-the-box", they can give you a big head-start.  Additionally, with the respective communities contributing modules, there is a good chance someone will have already done most of the work for you.  So, instead of spending a month coming up with a "quick" system, you could spend that month polishing a great system. :)

Some people poopoo the open source CMS's as having too steep a learning curve or for being to convoluted...  Yes, they are complicated, but my experience says it's worth it.

Up to you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me advise you: do not use SQLite for such websites. It is not that this DBMS is poor (it is really great, though!), but **it is not best suited for multiple users accessing your site at once**. Stick to MySQL, if this is the only choice you have aside SQLite.

Second, it would be **easier to use Open Source CMS**. You have two popular options as top choices:

- WordPress and
- Drupal,

**Drupal** has great architecture, **WordPress** is easier to work with. Both of them are really **powerful**, both of them have **countless modules available**, both of them can be used to set up a **small shopping site**.

Take a look at them and decide on your own. But for sure using **already written software will save you months** (at least) and will help you **benefit from the community support** (updates, help in development, possible workforce in case you need it).

Comment: Not true. SQLite handles thousands of read request easily. It only locks during writes. So it doesn't scale well if you site is writing a lot to the DB. If your site is primarily reads it will handle quite a bit of traffic. If you don't manage your transactions it will be a large bottleneck http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Comment: Just another bit "SQLite usually will work great as the database engine for low to medium traffic websites (which is to say, 99.9% of all websites). The amount of web traffic that SQLite can handle depends, of course, on how heavily the website uses its database. Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure is a conservative estimate, not a hard upper bound. SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic." via http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: @RTGibbons: Ok, so let me make it clearer. [SQLite site itself](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) mentions, that SQLite may not be best suited for (among others): **High-volume Websites**, **High Concurrency**. Of course you can assume OP does not need it, but let's face it: MySQL will not have such problems so soon ([unless OP will reach Facebook's size](http://gigaom.com/cloud/facebook-trapped-in-mysql-fate-worse-than-death/)).

Comment: Did you read the numbers for their estimated load of when you *might* need to think about using a different backend - 100K hits/day with cases hitting 10 times that. I think that can be constituted as multiple users. I'm tired of seeing people saying not to use things b/c they don't think they scale or understand the technology. SQLite especially, you don't always need a RDBMS to get the job done.

Comment: @RTGibbons: Do not misinterpret what I am saying - SQLite is great for many applications. Just consider the following facts: 1) OP is a beginner (means the code may be far from efficient, may call the database thousands of times for a single page request), 2) OP is not aware of SQLite limitations (means will probably hit the wall with this solution), 3) OP wants to build an application (not a _simple_ site), which means there will be even more chances to exhaust the soft limit of hits/day if site becomes successful.

Answer (score 1):

If I were in your shoes, I would shop around for an Open Source CMS that addresses at least 60% of your requirements. You didn't mention your level of coding skill, but chances are you adept enough to custom tailor any requirements the 'out of the box' code doesn't support.

Many open source applications are highly customizable, so you can safely add custom code to support your requirements without mucking up the source code. This is important so you can upgrade the CMS codebase without over-writing any of your custom code.

If needed, you can also stack an open source applciation upon a framework for even more out of the box functionality, for example, [drupal](http://drupal.com/) can be made to use certain [zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/) libraries.

You just need to have the expertise to pull in what you need from what's available and customize so it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Early this year i was involved in a very similar project, the requirements demanded i used Drupal, i was really new to the whole Drupal scene, and I must say it was a great experience, once you get past the learning curve and discover you get hooks for everything, you will get going doing your custom module that will do GD for image manipulation, I ended up using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or something like that to use the whole [ImageMagick framework](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), I understand your requirements are unique and different than mine, but I think Drupal will get you there faster than getting your out of the box solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, I agree with everyone else. Open Source. It will save you a bunch of time. Check out Joomla! with the K2 component (CCK) I believe it will handle much of what you're describing.